# How to tell if git branch was fetched from remote?

Tags: git

I'd like to know if some git branch was created locally (and hasn't been pushed to remote) or was fetched from remote and checkout out. What's an efficient way to do this (ie not involving checking out `master`)?

Answer (score 0):

Use the command mentioned below to determine that.

```
git branch -a --contains <branch-name>
```

In case a branch exists on remote as well you will see somethings like this

```
  * master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

Or else, if the branch was created on local like the test-branch, the output will be as follows.

```
  master
* test-branch
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

To clarify it further, the HEAD of the local-only branch will not point to origin/test-branch.

Comment: I have a branch that's been `fetch`ed but `git branch -a` is showing the tracking only for `master`, not the branch I explicitly `fetch`ed. Any idea what might be causing that?

Comment: Turns out I had to `git config --add 'remote.origin.fetch' …`.